# How to send message (in C) from one thread to another?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, pthreads

I'm trying to send a message from one thread to another. Each thread knows the thread ID of the other. How can I send a message between them?

I've already seen some proposed solutions (message queue, anonymous pipe, etc.) but honestly I didn't get them to work. Obviously I didn't understand the previous descriptions enough, hence this topic.

So to sum up, just the shortest possible way to send, let's say a message "Hello!" from thread to another thread, make the 2nd thread show it on stderr, and than send back to 1st thread message 'Hello back!'.

It's probably very easy and I didn't do a good job of researching, but I've been stuck for some time now, and can't find decent way to do this.

Comment: Use a mutex and an array

Comment: What you are describing are *inter-process communication* mechanisms, which is not really needed for communication between threads. Threads share the same address space. They could directly communicate, for example, using a global variable (with proper synchronization).

Comment: I've read about sharing address space. The thing is, even if right now there are only two threads, later there's going to be a lot of threads, or rather one main thread messaging with lots ot other threads. Global variable won't help me in such case I think.

And about mutex/array - I'll try to work this out. Didn't have luck with mutex so far.

Comment: Punch "C threadsafe message queue" into your favorite search engine.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't had time to look at it before yesterday. I've changed it a bit (fork creates a new process not a thread if I'm correct) but I got it too work. It was 5 am when I was done (and I wake up at 8 am for work ;] ) so I forgot to set it as correct.

Many thanks for this example, it helped me a lot.

Comment: Also thanks for anyone who gave his input in this topic. Even if I can use only one solution, I sure learned more ;]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example, it's pretty simple — first make a pipe with `pipe()`. [It creates two file descriptor](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) — one for reading, and the second for writing. Here we calling it two times to have both read and write sides. Then we calling fork *(that makes a second thread)*, and write/read messages through the pipes we created.

```
#include <poll.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int wait_n_read(int fd, char* buf, int szBuf) {
    struct pollfd pfd = {
        .fd      = fd,
        .events  = POLLIN,
        .revents = 0
    };
    poll(&pfd, 1, -1); //wait for an event
    int ret = read(fd, buf, szBuf);
    if (ret == -1) {
        perror("In read()");
    }
    return ret;
}

main(){
    int chan[4];
    enum{
        thread1_read  = 0, //read end for parent
        thread2_write = 1, //write end for child 
        thread2_read  = 2, //read end for child 
        thread1_write = 3  //write end for parent
    };
    if (pipe(&chan[thread1_read]) == -1 || (pipe(&chan[thread2_read]) == -1)){
        perror("In pipe");
        return 1;
    }
    switch(fork()) {
        case -1:
            perror("In fork()");
            return 1;
        case 0:{ //it's a child
            char buf[256];
            memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
            if (wait_n_read(chan[thread2_read], buf, sizeof(buf)-1) == -1)
                return 1;
            fputs(buf, stderr);
            const char helloback[] = "Hello back\n";
            write(chan[thread2_write], helloback, sizeof(helloback));
            return 0;
        }
        default: { //a parent
            const char hello[] = "Hello\n";
            write(chan[thread1_write], hello, sizeof(hello));
            char buf[256];
            memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
            if (wait_n_read(chan[thread1_read], buf, sizeof(buf-1)) == -1)
                return 1;
            fputs(buf, stderr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked for me :] I've changed it from fork to pthread, but other than that,  I've implemented the same thing. Huge thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but none of these answers, address the simple solution.   Use globals and   1. Use a mutex.   2. Do not use a mutex, for shut-down-coming flags.   3. (horrible, not portable, but works great) Do not use mutexs when claiming work for the thread using file rename() on aix/xlc.   Rename is automous, and will succed or fail.  On success, your thread, has the work.   On failure, nope, another thread won.   Port this solution to linux, and it will fail, misserably, because rename function is not automous for linux gcc.

Comment: I fail to see _rename_ being mentioned by other than yourself. Though I think _rename(2)_ is an atomic operation, using files for thread-synchronization seems to be a waste of resources.